# NPM does not update package properly

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm

In my React Native (`version 0.59.5`) application, I have installed and linked the latest version of [React Native Gesture Handler](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler)(`version 1.2.2`). Whenever I run the application on my simulator, I get the following message immediately after successfully building:

```
TypeError: param is not an Object. (evaluating "__isNative' in param')

This error is located at:
  inPanGestureHandler (at StackViewLayout.js:300)
  in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
  in withOrientation (at StackView.js:79)
  in RCTView (at View.js:45)
  in View (at Transitioner.js:215)
  in Transitioner (at StackView.js22)
  in StackView (created by Navigator)
  in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:12)
  in KeyboardAwareNavigator (created by SceneView)
  in SceneView (at createTabNavigator.js:39)
  in RCTView (at View.js:45)
  in View (at ResourceSavingScene.js:26)
  in ResourceSavingScene (at createBottomTabNavigator.js:113)
  in RCTView (at View.js:45)
  in View (at screens.native.js:83)
  in ScreenContainer (at createBottomTabNavigator.js:103)
  in RCTView (at View.js:45)
  in View (at createBottomTabNavigator.js:102)
  in TabNavigationView (at createTabNavigator.js:197)
```

However, when I reinstall the library without closing or restarting the simulator, using the following command:

```
npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler@latest
```

Immediately after I live reload (refresh the app), the error is gone and I can properly use my application.

What might have gone wrong? Why do I always have to reinstall the library for the error to get fixed?

Comment: What happens if you just run `npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler` without linking? Additionally, its a good idea to shut down the dev server before installing new packages with React Native.

Comment: If I do not link the library, I am getting different errors. I always install new packages before running the dev server, however, in this specific case I need to reinstall the package while the dev server is running in order to get rid of the error and get the app to work. Any idea on how to avoid this and fix the error in general?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing the following subspecs from my Podfile.
[image]